# How to create Update method inside the same page as the user profile?

Tags: android, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

So as you can see here's my profile page i just want to create an update method here. Is it possible to do inside this page for the update method? I'm still new with flutter development here. So if there's any method that can update inside this page it would be really helpful for me thank you. Because usually I only see that people would create a new page as for the database page but what I do with the login and register is that I do inside the page. So I just tryna see if there's a way to create update method inside a profile page

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter_user_profile/model/parking.dart';


class ParkingPage extends StatefulWidget {



  @override
  State<ParkingPage> createState() => _ParkingPageState();
}

class _ParkingPageState extends State<ParkingPage> {
  User? user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
  Parking loginuser = Parking();
  @override




  void initState(){
    super.initState();
    FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('parkingTech')
    .doc(user!.uid)
    .get()
    .then((value){
      this.loginuser = Parking.fromMap(value.data());
      setState(() {});
    });
  }

  // @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Color(0xFF121212),
      appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Color(0xFF121212),
          elevation: 0.0,
          title: Text('Parking Tech',
            style:TextStyle(
              color: Color(0xFFFFFFFF),
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            ),
          ),
          centerTitle:true,
          actions: [
            // Icon(Icons.menu,
            //   color:Colors.amber,
            //   size:40,
            // )
          ]
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          children:[
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center ,
              children:[
                CircleAvatar(
                    backgroundColor: Colors.amber,
                    radius: 100.0,
                    child: Center(
                      child: Text('P',
                        style:TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 80,
                          color: Color(0xFF121212),
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        ),
                      ),
                    )
                ),
              ],
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 15),
            Text("Parking time : ${loginuser.name} ",
              style:TextStyle(
                fontSize: 20,
                color: Colors.grey,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 10),
            Text('00 : 56 : 05',
              style:TextStyle(
                fontSize: 50,
                color: Colors.white,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 15),
            Text('P15 AED',
              style:TextStyle(
                fontSize: 30,
                color: Colors.blueGrey,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 15),
            Text('On Parking ',
              style:TextStyle(
                fontSize: 15,
                color: Colors.amber,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 15),
            Text('End Parking',
              style:TextStyle(
                fontSize: 20,
                color: Colors.white,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 12),
            Text('Extend Parking',
              style:TextStyle(
                fontSize: 20,
                color: Colors.white,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 12),


          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You can add any method to any class

Comment: i want to update to firebase inside this page, how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your use case correctly, you want to update your widget whenever the user object changes? That is what I suspect since you are calling it a 'profile page', and it seems like the data in this widget is dependent on the user.

You could listen to changes to the Firebase user object, and in the callback, you could then rebuild your widget. Here is the relevant snippet from the [documentation](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/auth/start#userchanges), adapted to your use case (untested):

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    FirebaseAuth.instance.userChanges().asyncMap((User? user) =>
        FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection('parkingTech')
            .doc(user!.uid)
            .get()
            .then((value) {
          this.loginuser = Parking.fromMap(value.data());
          setState(() {});
        }));
  }
```